# How to publish legacy android app with "unsafe encryption" error?

Tags: android-security

We use AES encryption with static key and static vector.
Encryption and decryption of data made on Windows, MacOS and Android.
We know it is not secure to store the key in the app and we do not care about security, we just need to be able to support legacy data format, **we need encryption not for security, but for back compatibility**. We know we do not provide any data security and our customers know it too. Is where any way to force Play Store to ignore the error and publish our app without moving encryption and decryption functions to NDK?

Comment: The question is not good fit for SO. Try on the Android SE site

Comment: @Vega can you please explain why it is not for stackoverflow?

Comment: Because it doesn't evolve programming, It should be about programming or related to programming. If you consider it is, then post the some code, error messages, or at least show your research in the matter. SO is not a tutorial site

Comment: @Vega so you are not familiar with the problem and did not understand the question. Thank you for your care. Take a look at this, if you have time: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9450925 Apps with this kind of "errors" cannot be published in store.